# How do we evaluate: $2\div2\div 2\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How does one solve: $2\div2\div2$ ?

You get either $2$ or $0.5$ depending on which operation you do first.

A friend told me that in situations like this you work from left to right and top to bottom.

In this case the correct answer is $0.5$.

Is this a concrete rule in mathematics or is the above expression simply incomplete and indeterminate?

If anyone knows of a link where that issue is clearly defined in writing that would be ideal.

Comment: Usually it is done left to right. However, this confusion is usually just completely avoided by unambiguous notation.

Comment: Use parentheses! I've only ever seen those situation in examples and poorly written code

Comment: Well, it could be $$\frac{2}{\displaystyle\frac{2}{2}}\quad\text{or}\quad\frac{\displaystyle\frac{2}{2}}{2}.$$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  If i'm understanding correctly, that point has already been discussed.

Answer (score 6):

While it's true that multiplication is [associative,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) e.g. $$a\cdot b \cdot c = (a\cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$$

[**Division** is **not** associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Non-associative), so given $2\div 2\div 2$ the statement is ambiguous.

Of course, by the **Constitution of Mathematical Evaluation of Operations,** when in doubt (and lacking parentheses,) we are to evaluate operations from ***left to right***, as a mathematical convention, in which we are to take $$2\div 2 \div 2 = (2\div 2)\div 2 = (1)\div 2 = 1\div 2 = \frac 12$$

But, the problem here is you can't assume that people will know how you arrived at one or another of the expressions.  And to make extra sure you are understood, welcome the use of parentheses!

So we need specify what we mean by using parentheses. Look at  $$(2\div 2) \div 2=\frac 12$$ which you see, is not equal to $$2\div (2\div 2)= 2$$

So one could answer, given $2 \div 2\div 2,$ that $$(2\div 2)\div 2 = \frac 12$$ whereas $$2\div (2\div 2)= 2.$$

Comment: Similarly, while addition **is associative** $$a+b+c = (a+b)+c = a+(b+c),$$ Subtraction **is not associative**.  E.g., given $8-5-2$, with  no parentheses used, by default, by Mathematical Convention, we should evaluate from left to right. Hence $a-b-c = (a-b)-c$.  Using an example: $8-5-2=(8-5)-2 = 1$.  But sometimes folks forget to emphasize the intended order in which to operate, so in this case, may have meant $8-5-2 = 8-(5-2)$.  In either case though, it's never going to hurt (and can only help) to use parentheses.

Comment: As far as you last question, Derek, see [order of operations, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Answer (score 4):

Left to right would be the general rule, but in practice no one would write an expression like that. Mathematicians prefer fractions to the division sign, so you'd see 
$$
\frac{2}{2/2} \text{ or } \frac{2/2}{2}.
$$
If you were writing a computer program you'd be sure to use parentheses to make your meaning clear.

Comment: "If you were writing a computer program you'd be sure to use parentheses..." unless you want your code as short as possible and know which one of the two options the code will choose

Comment: @vrugtehagel Maximally compact code is often a bad idea since people (not just interpreters and compilers) need to read programs. Except at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.